# Accessing email inbox through content provider

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to access the core application email using a content provider. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. For an example, check out the Android Developer site [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) and scroll down to the *Adding new values* section.

Comment: Yes, this post is useful. Thank you.

Comment: Hey phil, fetch the email in inbox from core application and listing in our own layout is possible through content provider or not? If yes how. And, if not what is the alternate way?

Comment: This second question is much more difficult. I would recommend opening a new question. You should be able to. After all, there are lots of examples of pulling contact info from contacts, such as [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Android/article.html#contentprovider_example), but I am having difficulty finding a good mail example.